# SQLite count example

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I am using SQLite in Android.
I have the query, query executed and how to print count from cursor.

```
Cursor dataCount = mDb.rawQuery("select count(*) from " + DATABASE_JOURNAL_TABLE, null);
```

I have no record in table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be by [getInt(index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29) as

```java
cursor.getInt(1); // this is for example, you have to adjust index in your code
```

Also cursor has a built in function [getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) to return row number so can also do like this:

```java
// assuming your table has `id` column as primary key or unique key.
Cursor dataCount = mDb.rawQuery("select id from " + DATABASE_JOURNAL_TABLE, null);
dataCount.getCount();
```

See [android devloper's doc for Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) for more information.

Comment: Your first solution is wrong, the query will return a "count(*)" column at index 0, so cursor.getInt(0) will return the table count. Your second solution will work but is bad practise, it will have no issues on a small scale, but using "select * from" to get the count on a database table with 30 columns and 10,000 rows will not perform well.....

Comment: @S-K' about first point, I was just giving example, I have no intention in using 1 as index. For clarification added a comment. Your second point is perfectly valid, getting * for large table is bad idea, one should get an unique key (mostly primary key) from the table and then get the count.

Comment: Selecting id is still poor practise, the aggregate count function is the best approach. You are abusing the getCount() method.

Answer (score 8):

You already have the correct approach.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select count(*) from " + DATABASE_JOURNAL_TABLE, null);

// ensure there is at least one row and one column
if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.getColumnCount() > 0) {
    cursor.close();
    return cursor.getInt(0);
} else {
    cursor.close();
    return 0;
}
```

You must check that there is at least 1 row and 1 column, if you provide a table that does not yet exist there will be no column to access and cursor.getInt(0) will throw an exception.

source: https://github.com/samkirton/SQLKing

Comment: what does the "cursor.moveToFirst()" method do in your case?  doesn't getCount iterate from first to last of the table?

Comment: needs to cursor.close() before returning!

Comment: While the Accepted answer may work (with some limitations/caveats as noted in its comments), this is a better answer.