# how to get sum of values of cursor retrieved values in Android

Tags: android

i have retrieved some values from DB using the query which is given below.

```
public Cursor getcredittranscation(String date)

{

String sql="SELECT A.Acc_No,A.Cust_Name, T.Trans_Amnt FROM TransactionTable "
            + "T LEFT JOIN AccMaster A on A.Acc_ID = T.Acc_ID "
            + "WHERE T.Trans_Date =? AND T.Trans_Type=? ORDER BY  T.Entry_Time asc";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{date, "credit"});

return cursor;
}
```

And in main activity i want to show these results as a report. Activity code is as given below.

```
try{

            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getdebittranscation(temp);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DisplayDebitDetails(c);
                    debittotal(c);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("Retrive Debit Error ", " "+e.getMessage());
            }
private void DisplayDebitDetails(Cursor c) {

            String tempdebit = debitView.getText().toString() + "  ";
            tempdebit= " \t"+tempdebit+ "\n\t" +c.getString(0) + "\t\t\t" 
                            + c.getString(1) + "\t\t\t" + c.getString(2);
                debitView.setText(tempdebit);

                Log.e("debit", "Acc No :"+c.getString(0) +"Name :"+c.getString(1)+ "Trans Amnt :"+c.getString(2));
            }
        }
        private void debittotal(Cursor c){

   int tmp = Integer.parseInt(debiTotalView.getText().toString()+" ");
            tmp = +tmp+Integer.parseInt(c.getString(2));
            debiTotalView.setText(tmp);
```

Retrieving and viewing all values is ok... But i need the sum of all values in String(2) . which is given in method debittotal(Cursor c). what is the error in that part ?? I am not getting total

Comment: `int records = c.getCount();` It will return total number of records. If 0 then no records to cursor. More than 0 will have records in Cursor. Dont forgot to `c.moveToFirst()` metod inside If condition.

Comment: you want no of records? or sum of all values retrieved from DB ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqlite count example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831085/sqlite-count-example)

Comment: sum of not all values retrieved. just values in String(2) only..@YograjShinde

Comment: what is result(total) you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any value... in retrieving the values.. for example, my result is like  
acc1  name1  300,
acc2  name2  200,
acc3  name3  150, @YograjShinde
etc.... I want the sum of 300+200+150

Answer (score 2):

you can use getCount() method

```
int number_of_records = cursor.getCount();
```

Comment: I only want the sum of values present in String(2).

Comment: thats a column !!! retrieved the number of items in single column same as retrieved the cursor count !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this and make sure that `debitTotalView.getText().toString()` is not **blank or null**

**initially that field value must be 0**  otherwise it will give you `NumberFormatException` for `invalid int` value

replace

```
int tmp = Integer.parseInt(debiTotalView.getText().toString()+" ");
            tmp = +tmp+Integer.parseInt(c.getString(2));
            debiTotalView.setText(tmp);
```

with

```
   int tmp = Integer.parseInt(debiTotalView.getText().toString().trim());
        tmp = +tmp+Integer.parseInt(c.getString(2));
        debiTotalView.setText(tmp+"");
```