# error in counting the number of a specific record in database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

how can I create a query that counts the number of an Specific record in database.
I tried this code:

```
 public int getContactsCount(String name) {
        String countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM database_names where _name ="+name;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        return cursor.getCount();


    }
```

but it did not work.
it says :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 26655
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: incomplete input (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT count(*) FROM database_names where _name =, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:948)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:559)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1427)
        at com.example.myapplication.database_names.getContactsCount(database_names.java:68)
        at com.example.myapplication.HazineHaActivity$1.onClick(HazineHaActivity.java:62)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite count example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831085/sqlite-count-example)

Comment: remove the + before your name..your query is ok

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is that you don't surround the parameter `name` in single quotes.
But the correct way to do it is to use a placeholder in your query and pass `name` as a parameter:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
  "SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM MY TABLE WHERE _NAME = ?", 
  new String[] {name}
);
```

Replace `db` with your SQLiteOpenHelper object.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  COUNT(id) as count from tblstudent where name='test'
```

Comment: If the table did not have column named **id** then the above would fail with column not found error. Using `count()` or `count(*)` would be a better answer as it's guaranteed to work irrespective of the columns in the table, perhaps amend your answer accordingly.

Comment: yeah.it is not compulsory that fire count on id only .you can get the count on any column name in that table. You will get the idea when you will call a big function and then get thousands of record. then it will reduce your performance.because if you use * then it will go through the whole table which is time-consuming.

Comment: You appear to not have read the comment. In many situations your answer would fail.  However your response is also incorrect. i.e. `count(an_existing_column)`, `count(*)` or `count()` will use the same scan/search to produce the same result. It would be the WHERE clause that may change the indexes used but even still all three will be the same. You have confused using SELECT * which may introduce a performance hit due to the potential need for more memory (CursorWindow fills) in Android terms and possibly more IO due to the greater number of columns requiring a larger amount of memory.